# Material-UI v5 with Typescript, sx prop type check fails

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm using Material UI v5 and noticed that sx prop type check fails when it is in my local environment. But if you enter [any codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/qyse26?file=/demo.tsx) mui provides you will see it works fine.

I've installed my app via [create-react-app typescript template](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/#installation) and added mui v5 following [instructions in docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/installation/).

Sx prop type check works fine in sandbox, see `hello: "world"` key value:
[image: Sx prop works fine on sandbox]

Sx prop type check fails in local:
[image]

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.9.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
    "@mui/material": "^5.8.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.7.13",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.4.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Vscode Typescript v4.6.4

Vscode Eslint v2.2.2

Comment: you can't put `hello: world` in there